# pmie_daily and pmlogger_daily services both failing to start on rhel server

Tags: performance, rhel9

I've searched and searched, and can't find much on this problem. Both the pmie_daily and pmlogger_daily services are failing to start on out RHEL server. They are part of the RHEL "Performance Co-Pilot (PCP)" system. One post I found said it was due to the log files being owned by root instead of pcp, but I checked, and our pmie log files are owned by pcp.

The service logs just say (pmie_daily log has similar entries):

```
pmlogger_daily.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
pmlogger_daily.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Started Process archive logs.
```

While the /var/log/pcp/pmie/localhost/pmie.log says:

```
pmie: metric mssql.memory_manager.stolen_node_memory not in namespace for pmcd local: (host localhost)
pmLookupName failed: Unknown metric name
```

Sounds bad, but I don't know what that means or how to fix it.

The /var/log/pcp/pmlogger/pmlogger_daily.log says:

```
pmlogger_daily: [control.d/local:26]
Error: no pmlogger instance running for host "local:"
... logging for host "local:" unchanged
pmlogger_daily: [control.d/local:26]
Warning: skipping log rotation because we don't know which pmlogger to signal
pmlogger_daily: [control.d/local:26]
Warning: current volume of current pmlogger not known, compression skipped
```

And the /var/log/pcp/pmie/pmie_daily.log says:

```
pmie_daily: Error: no pmie instance running for host "local:"
[/etc/pcp/pmie/control.d/local:5] ... inference engine for host "local:" unchanged
```

...both similar. Could this be the problem, and if so, how to fix?